# avr-gcc Makefile: Why is avr-size foo.out used / required?

Tags: makefile, avr, avr-gcc

```
# Link
game.out: game.o system.o
    avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega32u2 -Os -Wall $^ -o $@ -lm
    avr-size $@
```

What is the avr-size $@ used for / required for?

I understand that this is probably needed by the linker, but what does the linker actually do with this piece of information. Haven't been able to find anything online but maybe I haven't look hard enough. Any explanations / links to information would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: AVR microcontroller memory (both flash and RAM) is so limited that it's a good practice to keep an eye on your memory usage while you're developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not required at all as part of the build process; it simply displays information about the generated binary. The `avr-size` program is just the avr version of the `size` program, and you can find the corresponding manual page [online](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/size.1.html) or on your local system. From the description:

> The GNU size utility lists the section sizes and the total size
> for each of the binary files objfile on its argument list.  By
> default, one line of output is generated for each file or each
> module if the file is an archive.